# how do you "Press ENTER to continue, anything else to quit" in C++

Tags: c++

Sorry, I'm sure this question gets asked a million times. I've searched, and I've found answers for "Press ENTER to continue", but for the life of me, I can't find the answer to my question.

```
do{
   //something something
   cout<<"Press ENTER to continue or anything else to quit."<<endl;
   //Enter is pressed or something else
}while(Enter is pressed)
```

here's what I'm trying to use it for

```
do{
   cout<<"Enter value: ";
   cin>>value[n];

   cout<<"Enter 'Y' to continue, anything else to quit"<<endl;
   cin>>reply;
}while(reply == 'y' || reply == 'Y')
```

In place of "Enter 'Y' to continue. Anything else to quit." I just want an "Enter to continue, Q to quit".

*edit*: After implementing what Tony D showed, I now have

```
do{
    cout<<"Enter the person's first name, last name, and age."<<endl;
    cin>>list[n].firstName>>list[n].lastName>>list[n].age;

    n++;
    cout<<"Press ENTER to continue. 'Q' to quit. ";
    std::getline(std::cin, reply);
}while (std::getline(std::cin, reply) && reply != "Q" && reply != "q");
```

it works, but I feel like something is still wrong. If I do just `while (std::getline(std::cin, reply) && reply != "Q" && reply != "q");` 
Q or q won't exit the loop and Enter just takes me to the next line. I tried this as a do while and a while loop.

Comment: If your problem is just about changing the input loop, there shouldn't be so much irrelevant code.

Comment: Edited :) Sorry, I'm new here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, when you do streaming like this (adding error handling)...

```
if (!(cin>>list[n].firstName>>list[n].lastName>>list[n].age))
{
    std::cerr << "oops... unable to parse `firstname lastname age' from stdin... terminating\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

...the parsing of input for `age` terminates on and does not consume the first whitespace character following.  That means the terminating newline will always be left on the `cin` stream.  So, you need to do something to get rid of it.  A simple way to do that while making it clear that you're not interested in the rest of the line's content is:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

If you prefer to check everything really carefully, you could use `std::getline(std::cin, line)` to read the line of input into a `std::string`, then construct a `std::stringstream` with it, then parse out the content like this:

```
std::string line;
if (cin>>list[n].firstName>>list[n].lastName>>list[n].age))
{ 
     std::istringstream iss(line);
     if (!(iss >> firstName >> lastName >> age))
     {
        std::cerr << "oops... unable to parse `firstname lastname age' from stdin... terminating\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
     }

     char c;
     if (iss >> c)  // this should fail - no more non-whitespace content allowed...
     {
        std::cerr << "oops... extra input encountered after the age value... terminating\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
     }
}
```

Once we're sure you're reading the entire line of per-person input, for the loop termination itself it's probably easiest to use:

```
do
{
    ...
} while (std::getline(std::cin, my_string) && my_string != "Q" && my_string != "q");
```

That way, any newline characters will automatically be removed from the stream.  Using `std::cin.get()` to read a single character from the stream is possible and more efficient, but it's a little trickier handling the newline.  Can get fancier if you want to ignore leading whitespace, complain about other non-empty input etc..

Whatever you type may not reach the stream until you press enter, so they'll need to press 'Q' to quit.  To avoid that, you'd need OS-specific non-Standard code or libraries.  There are plenty of SO questions explaining how to read keys without waiting for enter.

---

If you need to tolerate errors and prompt the user to try again, the easiest approach is to read in a way that can't fail due to invalid input, then use a separate stream object when you're attempting the parsing that may fail.  The following shows how to parse a few variables out of a line of input:

```
std::string line;
while ((std::cout << "enter x y z (space separated): ") &&
       std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line); // input string stream with contents of last line read
    char c;
    if ((iss >> x >> y >> z) && !(iss >> c))
        // we successfully parsed out x, y and z, and there was no trailing
        // non-whitespace character, so all's good...
        break;
    std::cerr << "unable to parse 'x', 'y' and 'z' from input, or unexpected trailing text\n";
    std::cerr << "please try again\n";
}
```

This way, `iss` may enter a bad state due to merely bogus user input but is recreated with the next line's content anyway.  `std::cin` only fails on unrecoverable issues (end-of-file, hardware error etc).  That avoids having to reset any stream state, which is a painful thing to have to do, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/132422 for an example program showing how.

Comment: Well I'd want it to be ENTER pressed, loop continues. Q, then ENTER, loops quits. What does cin.get() do?

Comment: "want it to be ENTER pressed, loop continues. Q, then ENTER, loops quits" - that's what the code in my answer does.  "What does cin.get() do?" - it reads the next character from the stream, so you can compare to '\n' to see if enter's been pressed before 'Q' or 'q', but if someone concatenates input from another operating system there might be e.g. a Carriage Return character hanging around afterwards that gets seen by your next `cin >> value[n];` - that probably won't matter in your case, if you've left the stream at the default behaviour of skipping whitespace.

Comment: Thanks. I added std::getline(std::cin, reply); in the loop, and it runs. Is that what I was supposed to do, or am I doing extra steps and missing something?

Comment: it sounds like you're probably missing something though I can't be sure without seeing your updated code; `getline` can be called in the `while()` condition at the end of the loop, rather than "in the loop", making it trivial to test both that the `getline` itself succeeded and to test whether the line content itself contains "Q"... just copy/paste the entire `while(...)` clause from my answer into your code, and put a `std::string my_string;` *before* the loop.

Comment: `cout<<"Press ENTER to continue. 'Q' to quit. ";
        std::getline(std::cin, reply);
    }while (std::getline(std::cin, reply) && reply != "Q" && reply != "q");` edited the OP as well. `std::string reply;` is in there. `}while (std::getline(std::cin, reply) && reply != "Q" && reply != "q");` by itself won't let me exit the loop and Enter just takes me to the next line.

Comment: Ok, I've read more carefully over what you do inside the loop, and the `>>` operations you do will terminate after seeing and without consuming any whitespace after the age, which is why you've found you need an extra `getline()` inside the loop to completely read that line of input, so that the `while(getline(...)...` sees the next "Enter or Q" line.  You can also use `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
` instead of the `getline` inside the loop, for which you'll need to `#include <limits>`.  Adding this to the answer....

Comment: Thanks. Runs good. One more question. for the if to check for errors, `if (!(cin>>list[n].firstName>>list[n].lastName>>list[n].age))` how would I write it to, instead of exit, just not accept that input and try again? For example, I typed in Brandon H Jones 32, just say not correct and go back.

Comment: @jova33: good question... trickier than it feels it ought to be too... I need some space so will append to my answer.